# How do i pass resources to Jobs so it can be accessible to it's ops

Tags: python, dagster

I am new to dagster and I'm trying to pass a resource to a dagster op through the job that it's called from I am having issue even after following the docs, I am not sure if I need to pass config again to jobs nothing seems to work. Here is the code.

Error `dagster.core.errors.DagsterInvalidConfigError: Error in config for job Error 1: Missing required config entry "resources" at the root.`

````
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


@op
def return_one(context):
    context.log.info(f'return_one {os.environ.get("BUCKET")}')
    return 1


@op(required_resource_keys={"boto3_connection"})
def add_two(context, i: int):
    context.log.info(f'##### {context.resources.boto3_connection.get_client()}')
    return i + 2


@op
def multi_three(i: int):
    return i * 3


class Boto3Connector(object):
    def __init__(self, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
        self.aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id
        self.aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key


    def get_client(self, resource="s3"):
        session = boto3.session.Session()

        session_client = session.client(
            service_name=resource,
            aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key,
        )
        return session_client


@resource(
    config_schema={
        'aws_access_key_id': StringSource,
        'aws_secret_access_key': StringSource
    })
def boto3_connection(context):
    return Boto3Connector(
        context.resource_config['aws_access_key_id'],
        context.resource_config['aws_secret_access_key']
    )


@job(resource_defs={'boto3_connection': boto3_connection})
def my_job():
    multi_three(add_two(return_one()))```
````

Answer (score 1):

My problem was assuming resources config are passed down automatically but you have to specify them on your jobs config. So just added the config.

```
@job(resource_defs={'boto3_connection': boto3_connection},
        config={'resources':
        { "boto3_connection": {
            "config": {
                "aws_access_key_id": {"env": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"},
                "aws_secret_access_key": {"env": "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"},
            }
        }}})
def my_job():
   multi_three(add_two(return_one()))`
```

Was pointed in the right direction on the  [dagster slack](https://dagster-slackin.herokuapp.com/)